# How to read CSV file which is being downloaded by a Javascript button

Tags: javascript, python, csv

I try to automatically extract data from a page in Python 3.6:
https://xxx.xxx/xxx/call/?period_from=20-11-2017&period_to=20-11-2017&direction=0&recordings=0&totalize_on=0&page=

Currently I have to manually press the export which triggers generation of an csv file of that table:

The export button triggers the following url:
https://xxx.xxx/xxx/call/export?period_from=20-11-2017&period_to=20-11-2017&direction=0&recordings=0&totalize_on=0&page=

I tried the following however it returns the raw html page to me, not the CSV file which is downloaded by opening the URL.

```
CSV_URL = 'https://xxx.xxx/xxx/call/export?period_from=20-11-2017&period_to=20-11-2017&direction=0&recordings=0&totalize_on=0'

session=requests.Session()
information=session.get(CSV_URL)
decoded_information=information.content.decode('utf-8')
data=decoded_information.splitlines()
data=csv.DictReader(data)

for row in data:
    print(row)
```

So to be clear, I understand how to download a file directly by using requests, but in this case there is no direct link to the file I want to download.

Comment: `there is no direct link` ... yet you say `The export button triggers the following url` ... which looks like a link you can download

Comment: Without the actual URL it will be difficult to help.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the 'network' tab of chrome developer tools? you might have to send certain headers or cookies with your request. In dev tooles there's usually even a "copy as CURL command" or the like.